# Running Updates on a large, heavily used table

Tags: sql

I have a large table (~170 million rows, 2 nvarchar and 7 int columns) in SQL Server 2005 that is constantly being inserted into. Everything works ok with it from a performance perspective, but every once in a while I have to update a set of rows in the table which causes problems. It works fine if I update a small set of data, but if I have to update a set of 40,000 records or so it takes around 3 minutes and blocks on the table which causes problems since the inserts start failing.

If I just run a select to get back the data that needs to be updated I get back the 40k records in about 2 seconds. It's just the updates that take forever. This is reflected in the execution plan for the update where the clustered index update takes up 90% of the cost and the index seek and top operator to get the rows take up 10% of the cost. The column I'm updating is not part of any index key, so it's not like it reorganizing anything.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be sped up? My thought now is to write a service that will just see when these updates have to happen, pull back the records that have to be updated, and then loop through and update them one by one. This will satisfy my business needs but it's another module to maintain and I would love if I could fix this from just a DBA side of things.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Could you post the table definition (including primary key, indexes, etc), any triggers on the table, and the actual update query itself?

Comment: @Adrian - But if the updated fields are not in the clustered index (or apparently any other index) why would the execution plan be showing a clustered index update?

Comment: @Dems my guess, purely a guess based on data at hand, is that it is moving table data on disk so it is updating pointers to where the data actually is moved. Why it would be doing it... no idea; maybe the bd is trying to optimize sth. Normally, I wouldn't expect this to happen every time!

Comment: There's a site dedicated to ‘DBA sides of things’, http://dba.stackexchange.com, you could try posting your question there too.

Comment: Oops, this was my first post to stack and I was under the impression I'd get emails when the question had reponses on it. That didn't happen so sorry I wasn't here to offer any extra info. I commented on some answers below.  I ended up writing the service since it met the needs I have. If anyone still wants to see the table/update statement, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mos brute-force (and simplest) way is to have a basic service, as you mentioned. That has the advantage of being able to scale with the load on the server and/or the data load.

For example, if you have a set of updates that *must* happen *ASAP*, then you could turn up the batch size. Conversely, for less important updates, you could have the update "server" slow down if each update is taking "too long" to relieve some of the pressure on the DB.

This sort of "heartbeat" process is rather common in systems and can be *very* powerful in the right situations.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it might reorganise pages if you update the nvarchar columns.
Depending on what the update does to these columns they might cause the record to grow bigger than the space reserved for it before the update. 
(See explanation now nvarchar is stored at http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/physical-database-design-consideration.html.)

So say a record has a string of 20 characters saved in the nvarchar - this takes 20*2+2(2 for the pointer) bytes in space. This is written at the initial insert into your table (based on the index structure). SQL Server will only use as much space as your nvarchar really takes.

Now comes the update and inserts a string of 40 characters. And oops, the space for the record within your leaf structure of your index is suddenly too small. So off goes the record to a different physical place with a pointer in the old place pointing to the actual place of the updated record.

This then causes your index to go stale and because the whole physical structure requires changing you see a lot of index work going on behind the scenes. Very likely causing an exclusive table lock escalation.

Not sure how best to deal with this. Personally if possible I take an exclusive table lock, drop the index, do the updates, reindex. Because your updates sometimes cause the index to go stale this might be the fastest option. However this requires a maintenance window.

Comment: You can also DISABLE an index before doing the updates to avoid its rebuilding. The PAGE->TABLE locks - we have a case of clear big number of PAGE locks here ASFAS I got it. The 170m records would hardly be blocked by 40k records although it would >5k locks! :)) . Plus I would also recommend to PARTITION this big table it it's not done YET. Thanks mates.

Comment: The update is not touching the nvarchar columns, just the int columns so the data shouldn't be reorganizing.  @Sergey, I looked into partitioning, but I didn't see a good way of maintaining the partitions. It probably would meet my performance needs, but would come with a bit of maintenance baggage.

Answer (score 1):

You should batch up your update into several updates (say 10000 at a time, TEST!) rather than one large one of 40k rows.

This way you will avoid a table lock, SQL Server will only take out 5000 locks (page or row) before esclating to a table lock and even this is not very predictable (memory pressure etc). Smaller updates made in this fasion will at least avoid concurrency issues you are experiencing.

You can batch the updates using a service or firehose cursor.

Read this for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx

Hope this helps

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Its wired that your analyzer is saying it take time to update the clustered Index . Did the size of the data change when you update ?  Seems like the varchar is driving the data to be re-organized which might need updates to index pointers(As KMB as already pointed out) . In that case you might want to increase the % free sizes on the data and the index pages  so that the data and the index pages can grow without relinking/reallocation . Since update is an IO intensive operation ( unlike read , which can be buffered ) the performance also depends on several factors

1) Are your tables partitioned by data 2) Does the entire table lies in the same SAN disk ( Or is the SAN striped well ?) 3) How verbose is the transaction logging . Can the buffer size of the transaction loggin increased to support larger writes to the log to suport massive inserts ?

Its also important which API/Language are you using? e.g JDBC support a batch update feature which makes the updates a little bit efficient if you are doing multiple updates .